# Doubly linked list, add node in-order

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I want to keep my doubly linked list sorted all the time and keep the head and the tail node pointers updated. I managed to keep the head pointer updated in all operations but I can not keep track of the tail pointer. It only shows the last element as `tail->info` but can not go back as doing `tail=tail->prev;` here is my code:

```
AddInOrder(node* &head, node* &tail, int number) {     

    node *ptr=head; 

    if (head==NULL || number<head->info) {       

        node*temp=new node;

        temp->info=number; 
        temp->next=head;   
        temp->prev=NULL;
        head=temp;   
        tail=temp;    
        return 0;
    }

    while(ptr->next!=NULL && ptr->next->info<number) {         
        ptr=ptr->next;                                        
    }

    node*temp=new node;              
    temp->info=number;
    temp->next=ptr->next;
    temp->prev=ptr;
    ptr->next=temp;

    while(ptr->next!=NULL) {
        ptr=ptr->next;                 
    }

    tail=ptr;             

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What were the issues you found when you used the debugger?

Comment: "but can not go back as doing `tail=tail->prev;`" - I'm trying to fathom a situation where you would ever *want* to do that in the first place, as if anything it will put your `tail` pointer somewhere it shouldn't be; *not* on the last node of the list.

Comment: let's say I type 6,9,1,2,3 it displays1,2,3,6,9 when I start displaying  them from the head pointer but starting from the tail to the head it gives 9 then 6 and then it stops where it shouldnt and contiune like 3,2,1

Comment: I want to print the list in reverse so I start from the tail and go back

Comment: You're not setting `ptr->prev` when you link a new node in. And when you add a new node to the head of the list you're wiping out your `tail` pointer.

Comment: I don't have a problem with linking a new node.I just can't figure out how to update the tail in all the conditions.Yes when I add to the head it is a problem with the tail for example@JonathanPotter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonathanPotter was right. "You're not setting ptr->prev when you link a new node in." that is the problem. 
this code works fine for me. see the modification, added some part for setting prev node. code may be little messy but you may understand the logic and write a better code.

```
int AddInOrder(node* &head, node* &tail, int number) 
{     
    node *ptr=head; 
    node*temp=new node;
    temp->info=number; 

    if ( head==NULL )
    {
        temp->next=head;   
        temp->prev=NULL;
        head=temp;
        tail = temp;

        return 0;
    }

    if ( number<head->info )
    { 
        temp->next=head;   
        temp->prev=NULL;

        head->prev = temp;
        head=temp;
        return 0;
    }

    while(ptr->next!=NULL && ptr->next->info<number) 
    {         
        ptr=ptr->next;    
        continue;
    }

    if (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr->next->prev = temp;
    }
    temp->next=ptr->next;
    temp->prev=ptr;
    ptr->next=temp;

    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
            ptr=ptr->next;                 
    }

    tail=ptr;             

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still same problem.Goes correctly with next bonds but when I start from the tail and want to go back with prev bonds,it does not go back correctly.I think I have problem with the prev connections anyway thanks for your interest i will work more on this.